# What are the differences between 真ん中, 中心 and 中央?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Could someone please explain the differences in usage and meaning? It would be nice with some example sentences as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions mostly taken from Goo/デジタル大辞泉（小学館）

[真ん中](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/210539/meaning/m0u/%E7%9C%9F%E3%82%93%E4%B8%AD/) is the most limited of the three. It only applies to 距離・場所・順序など and means the exact center/middle.

- 町の真ん中にある建物
- 三人兄弟の真ん中

[中央](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/142993/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%AD%E5%A4%AE/) includes the definition of 真ん中. It also means ある組織や機関の中で、最も重要な機能をになっているところ. That is to the say sub-organizations that are centrally important to an organization. For example,

> 党の中央

references the central/ruling committee of a party. Accordingly, it can also refer to the central/national government.

[中心](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/143402/meaning/m0u/%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83/) includes the definition of 真ん中, but also includes a few other definitions of note.

1. 物事の集中する場所。また、最も重要な位置にある物や人。また、その位置。

   - 大阪を中心とした関西の特徴 means with Osaka as the central example, the unique characteristics of Kansai region.
   - 話題の中心 means a central/major topic of conversation.
2. The center of a circle: [image: 中心]
3. The barycenter/center of gravity in physics. 質量中心. It is also called 重心
4. こころの内。心中{しんちゆう}. The inside of your heart.

Comment: When you quote and paraphrase a substantial portion of a definition like this, you really need to cite your source.  In this case, it looks like your source is 大辞泉, so it needs to be clearly marked as such.

Comment: @snailboat thanks for reminding me. I honestly thought I did, but apparently I forgot to do so in the end.